# Why is there a need for more edit approvals when I can edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Sometimes, there is an edit made by users with not enough rep. So I click, and sometimes approve. There, I have a message saying "2 more users needs to approve for the edit to take place", or something similar.

I have the privilege to edit. Why isn't my approval enough? If I think the edit is worth it, that means it's an edit I want to see. So I could edit the post right away.

I don't get the thinking behind this.

Comment: One word: robo-reviewers

Comment: @JanDvorak robo-reviewers don't have enough rep to edit themselves.

Comment: umm... don't you need 2k to review edits?

Comment: Oh, maybe. Then if users are trusted to edit, why should they not be trusted to approve edits?

Comment: People don't robo-edit, but they do robo-review

Comment: If you improve the edit while reviewing, it will not wait for another reviewers to review the edit.

Comment: @JanDvorak: That's not true, there are also robo-edit-users out there which just change the spelling of one word f.e. and don't fix anything else.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby ah, right. These don't really hurt (I know, CW and bumping), though. Robo-approvals are much worse than trivial edits.

Answer (score 3):

As [Jan Dvorak](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187978/why-is-there-a-need-for-more-edit-approvals-when-i-can-edit#comment578427_187978) [repeatedly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187978/why-is-there-a-need-for-more-edit-approvals-when-i-can-edit#comment578432_187978) [emphasized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187978/why-is-there-a-need-for-more-edit-approvals-when-i-can-edit/187984#comment578433_187978), the requirement for the approval of 3 users is a measure to counter robo-reviewing (where a reviewer simply approve/reject without looking in order to get reviewing-related badges quickly).

While you yourself know that you are not robo-reviewing, the system doesn't know that. Hence the need for the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

If the suggested edit is for a popular tag at a peak time then it doesn't take too long for the rest of the approve/rejections to come in and sort out the edit - so normally just waiting is fine.

What I tend to do is if it's not going to receive much attention, or there's not many reviewers out (or the most active ones have already used up their votes for the period), and I can absolutely convince myself it's a good edit, then I'll hit the "Improve" button and bar any minor edits required to the post, save the changes.

The one that has bugged me in the past is that if a suggested edit is pending, then I can't make a direct edit. Again, if the proposed edit is good, I'll improve and merge my edit in, otherwise, I'll put my edit in anyway and untick the edit was helpful box just so it's not limboing / blocking other edits / suggested edits.